# angularjs karma test typeerror $route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to test a controller for angularjs using karma, the controller inject a $route to get the current path but when I try to run karma test on it I get.

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object( evaluating '$route.current')
```

Here is my controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('EditController',['$scope', '$http', '$route', function($scope,
$http,$route){

    var myId = $route.current.params.myId;  
    $scope.var1 = 'var1';  
    console.log(myId);
}]);
```

Here is my Karma file:

```
'use strict';
describe('Controller: EditController', function(){
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    var EditCtrl,scope,route;

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller,$rootScope,$route,$http){
     scope=$rootScope.$new();
     EditCtrl = $controller('EditCtrl',{
        $scope:scope,
        $route:route
     });
    }));

    it('should have var1 equal to "var1"',function(){
        expect(scope.var1).toEqual('var1');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: watch out EditCtrl its not the same of  EditController I think you don't need to inject $route and $http

Answer (score 2):

Your `beforeEach` hook isn't injecting the `$route` service. Change it to this.

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller,$rootScope,$route,$http){
 scope=$rootScope.$new();
 route = $route;
 EditCtrl = $controller('EditCtrl',{
    $scope:scope,
    $route:route
 });
}));
```

You may also want to mock the `$route.current` object in case it isn't instantiated properly, since there's no routing going on in your test. In which case you could just add

`$route.current = { params: { myId: 'test' } };`

in the hook as well.